# WPF dependency injection when navigate to new page

Tags: wpf, dependency-injection

I have a problem because I don't know how to inject service into the page.
This is how my App.xaml.cs look like

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public IServiceProvider ServiceProvider { get; set; }
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; set; }

    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", false, true);

        Configuration = builder.Build();

        var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
        ConfigureServices(serviceCollection);
        Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);
        ServiceProvider = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();
        var mainWindow = ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<MainWindow>();
        mainWindow.Show();
    }

    private void ConfigureServices(ServiceCollection serviceCollection)
    {
        serviceCollection.AddTransient<IPage1ViewModel, Page1ViewModel>();
        serviceCollection.AddTransient(typeof(MainWindow));
    }
}
```

I have MainWindow with frame, in frame I have default page called Home.xml with button.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfDITest.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfDITest"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Menu Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">
        <MenuItem Header = "Help" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <MenuItem Name="about" Header = "about t" HorizontalAlignment = "Stretch"/>
        </MenuItem>
    </Menu>

    <Frame Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Source="/Views/Home.xaml" NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden" />
</Grid>
```

When you click button it navigates you to new page called Page1.

```
public partial class Home : Page
{
    public Home()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

  

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var uri = "/Views/Page1.xaml";
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri(uri, UriKind.Relative));
    }
}
```

I want to inject IPage1ViewModel to my Page1 so I thought I would just inject service to constructor like in asp.net apps but the problem is Navigation service fires constructor without parametress so right now I dont know how to achieve this.

```
public partial class Page1 : Page
{
    private readonly IPage1ViewModel _page1ViewModel;
    public Page1(IPage1ViewModel page1ViewModel)
    {
        _page1ViewModel = page1ViewModel;
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public Page1() //this constructor fires
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        GetData();
    }

    public void GetData()
    {
        _page1ViewModel.GetTitle(); // How to get this?
    }
}
```

Page1ViewModel

```
public class Page1ViewModel : IPage1ViewModel
{
    public Page1ViewModel()
    {

    }

    public string GetTitle()
    {
        return "Welcome";
    }
}
```

Is it a good idea to use dependency injection in my case? If so, how do I solve my problem?

Comment: Try to understand what's happened in this [sample project](https://github.com/SingletonSean/wpf-tutorials/tree/master/NavigationMVVM) 
This project is using MVVM and DI. But if you can't understand ping me to give you short example.

Comment: @Milad
I found this solution before but it is too complicated for me, I would be grateful for something simple enough for him to understand the topic.

Comment: Personally, i would datatemplate the ui out from a viewmodel. You then can instantiate your viewmodel however you like and DI into it won't be such a problem.  I would also recommend you use usercontrols rather than pages.  Navigation then becomes a matter of resolving the viewmodel out di. Also, avoid complex logic directly in a ctor.  If it fails somewhere then you've got no object. When it requires some data or whatever takes a while to obtain the you have a wait before anything can happen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would have to instantiate the `Page` explicitly using a factory (Abstract Factory pattern or a factory delegate).

When you instantiate controls via XAML, either by defining an element or via URI, the XAML engine will always create the instance using the default constructor (which is therefore mandatory for XAML instantiations).

If your control must use dependency injection, you must instantiate them explicitly, so that you can call the appropriate constructor, usually with the help of a factory.

1. Make `Home` request a `Page1` factory delegate (a `Func<Page1>`) as constructor dependency. Then use it to create the `Page1` instance explicitly:

```cs
public partial class Home : Page
{
  private Func<Page1> Page1Factory { get; }

  public Home(Func<Page1> page1Factory)
  {
    InitializeComponent();
    this.Page1Factory = page1Factory; 
  }

  private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
    Page1 nextPage = this.Page1Factory.Invoke();
    NavigationService.Navigate(nextPage);
  }
}
```

2. Register the `Page1` type (with an appropriate lifetime) and its factory delegate (or alternatively an abstract factory type)

**.NET [Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0) example**

```cs
private void ConfigureServices(ServiceCollection serviceCollection)
{
  serviceCollection.AddTransient<IPage1ViewModel, Page1ViewModel>()
    .AddTransient<MainWindow>()

    .AddTransient<Page1>()
    .AddSingleton<Func<Page1>>(serviceProvider => serviceProvider.GetService<Page1>);
}
```

**Equivalent Autofac example**

```cs
private void ConfigureServices(ContainerBuilder containerBuilder)
{
  _ = containerBuilder.RegisterType<Page1ViewModel>()
    .As<IPage1ViewModel>()
    .InstancePerDependency();
  _ = containerBuilder.RegisterType<MainWindow>().InstancePerDependency();
  _ = containerBuilder.RegisterType<Page1>().InstancePerDependency();

  // Autofac will automatically create the Func<T> instance, when it detects a corresponding constructor parameter.
  // But you can define the delegate instance explicitly if required.
  // The following line is therefore optional.
  _ = containerBuilder
    .Register<Func<Page1>>(context => context.Resolve<Page1>)
    .SingleInstance();

  IContainer container = containerBuilder.Build();
}
```

3. Normally, you would bind the UI elements of `Page1` to its `DataContext`. Therefore, you must set the injected view model as `DataContext`. Also, you should remove the default constructor (or at least make it `private`) as it will not initialize the type properly (the view model i.e. `DataContext` is missing). Additionally, a `public` method named `Get...` is expected to return a result. Either rename the method or let it return the result or make it at least `private` too.

```cs
public partial class Page1 : Page
{
    private IPage1ViewModel Page1ViewModel { get; }

    // This constructor also calls the private default constructor
    // (in case this type has multiple constructor overloads. 
    // Otherwise, move the private default constructor code to this constructor).
    public Page1(IPage1ViewModel page1ViewModel) : this()
    {
      this.Page1ViewModel = page1ViewModel;
      this.DataContext = this.Page1ViewModel;
      Initialize();
    }

    private Page1()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Initialize()
    {
      this.Page1ViewModel.GetTitle();
    }
}
```

4. Because it is recommended to use data binding ([Data binding overview (WPF .NET)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/?view=netdesktop-6.0)), your view model classes must implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` (see [Microsoft docs for an example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.propertychanged?view=netcore-3.1#examples)

Comment: Since the Home class also needed a parameter to run the delegate you created (the Home class constructor was created by default without a parameter), I did something similar to the Page1 class. Now It works, thank you.

Comment: This is what I need to do with Autofac DI. Would you be able to provide an example?
Thank you.

Comment: Thank you @BionicCode. 
As Tomi described, I created a sample project with your suggestions, but I couldn't solve the home page issue. I would appreciate it if you could help me fix that.
this is a sample project same as Tomi project: [GitHub repository](https://github.com/raminmjj/WpfAppWithDI)

Comment: @BionicCode, thank you. I made the changes and now everything works fine. The changes have been pushed to the git repository.

Comment: @RaminAlirezaee Good luck with your project!

Comment: Can you please delete the conversation to keep the thread clean? Thank you!